# Structuring files in a .NET project

Tags: .net, directory-structure

In a MVC application you get a predefined project skeleton with directories for Models, Views and Controllers.
When creating a class library or a console application however you get no such project skeleton.

As a project grows a lot of files eventually accumulate in the project's root directory. Hence a desire to somehow group the files may arise.

In projects with co-workers, I've come across files grouped into directories named Interfaces, Enums and Extensions. In line with this thinking perhaps directories for filters, attributes and abstract classes could also be used. I guess this could be called "language construct based grouping" and while any consistent grouping arguably may be better than none I believe this type of grouping strategy might not be the most suitable one.

Looking at Microsoft source code on GitHub I see that interfaces and their implementations tend to reside in the same directory and that while grouping of files exists, it is not done based on the language construct. I find it difficult to exactly pinpoint what the grouping strategy is.

I realize that there might not be any crystal clear answer since what needs to be grouped may be specific to the particular project at hand.
However, I am looking for helpful advice and guiding principles on how to figure out *what* should be grouped and *how* it should be grouped.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find that most projects try to 1) keep things together which belong together (e.g., enums which are used by a particular set of classes are grouped not in an `enums` folder but in a folder with those classes), and 2) to place things in a structure which mimics their namespace hierarchy (just as your Model namespaces will be MyProject.Areas.MyArea.Models in an MVC project, and `Areas`, `MyArea`, and `Models` are all subfolders.

That said, the reason you see variation is that there is not a single standard way to organize source code - you're left to decide that as an organization.  This is not a bad thing: your group may conceptualize things differently than the next group, and so will have a different project structure.  Over time, the structure will morph to what makes sense to the group, even if you start out with someone else's idea of the right way to structure things.

Comment: If the structure morph over time, then anything depending on the library will break as the structure changes.

Comment: When I group related files, how do I know if they should be in a folder in the project, or in a separate project?

Comment: Ask yourself, Can these things stand by themselves, as a unit?  Nobody can answer this question but you, really.